# How to sort/order data, by Date in div (JavaScript/React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, time

im little bit stuck here, i get my data from Firebase, but as much as i try i fail to sort my shown meetings, by date => time.

Can anyone help me how to show this first ordered by date, and same dates order by time?

Thank you!

```
<div>
  {/* {consultation && consultation.map(item => item.advisor)} */}
  {rows && rows.map(row =>
  <div key={row.id}>
    <div>{row.date}</div>
    <div>{row.time}</div>
    <div>{row.status}</div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: please add some sample data of `rows`

Comment: what sort of data is there for `row.time`

Comment: @aeXuser264  date looks like this 22. 9. 2020, its Timestamp converted by this
 const myDate = new Date(date.toDate()).toLocaleDateString("cs-CZ");

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress time is string, 11:00 - 11:30 every time in this format, its enought to order it by first number "11:00" because all meeting will have same lenght

Comment: @DimaMalko `rows.sort((a, b) => a.time < b.time ? -1 : 1)`

Comment: @aeXuser264 for some reason i cant tag you in your answer down there, so i tag you here to thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ur,
Date format is something like this `dd. mm. yyyy` where `dd` and `mm` is not padded by zero and starts with 1.
Time format `HH:MM - 11:30`, u only need the starting time not the end (**`HH:MM`** <strike>`- 11:30`</strike>).

Try something like this before passing to render,

```
rows.sort((a, b) => datetimeToTS(b.date, b.time) - datetimeToTS(a.date, a.time))

function datetimeToTS(dateStr, timeStr) {
  const dateMatch = dateStr.match(/(?<dd>\d+).\s*(?<mm>\d+).\s*(?<yy>\d+)/)
  const timeMatch = timeStr.match(/^(?<hh>\d+):(?<mm>\d+)/)
  
  if (dateMatch == null || timeMatch == null)
    throw new Error('Could match date/time format');
  
  const date = new Date(
    dateMatch.groups.yy,
    dateMatch.groups.mm-1,
    dateMatch.groups.dd,
    timeMatch.groups.hh,
    timeMatch.groups.mm
  );
  return date.getTime()
}
```

This function uses js and converts to date&time to timestamp. You may use *momentjs* of something like that to replace it

So, all of em would be,

```
const sortedRows = rows.sort((a, b) => datetimeToTS(b.date, b.time) - datetimeToTS(a.date, a.time))

return <div>
  {/* {consultation && consultation.map(item => item.advisor)} */}
  {sortedRows && sortedRows.map(row =>
  <div key={row.id}>
    <div>{row.date}</div>
    <div>{row.time}</div>
    <div>{row.status}</div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  )}
</div>
```

You might wanna use `useMemo` as it might be little expensive to sort at every rendering.

Interactive example,

```js
// Some randomly generated data
const row = [{
  "date": "1. 9. 2020",
  "time": "4:00 - 4:30"
}, {
  "date": "1. 9. 2020",
  "time": "12:00 - 12:30"
}, {
  "date": "1. 9. 2020",
  "time": "2:00 - 2:30"
}, {
  "date": "3. 9. 2020",
  "time": "3:00 - 3:30"
}, {
  "date": "4. 9. 2020",
  "time": "7:00 - 7:30"
}, {
  "date": "3. 9. 2020",
  "time": "2:00 - 2:30"
}, {
  "date": "4. 9. 2020",
  "time": "12:00 - 12:30"
}, {
  "date": "1. 9. 2020",
  "time": "8:00 - 8:30"
}, {
  "date": "2. 9. 2020",
  "time": "11:00 - 11:30"
}, {
  "date": "4. 9. 2020",
  "time": "6:00 - 6:30"
}, {
  "date": "11. 9. 2020",
  "time": "9:00 - 9:30"
}, {
  "date": "12. 9. 2020",
  "time": "9:00 - 9:30"
}, {
  "date": "13. 9. 2020",
  "time": "6:00 - 6:30"
}, {
  "date": "14. 9. 2020",
  "time": "4:00 - 4:30"
}, {
  "date": "15. 9. 2020",
  "time": "5:00 - 5:30"
}, {
  "date": "16. 9. 2020",
  "time": "12:00 - 12:30"
}, {
  "date": "17. 9. 2020",
  "time": "12:00 - 12:30"
}, {
  "date": "18. 9. 2020",
  "time": "5:00 - 5:30"
}, {
  "date": "19. 9. 2020",
  "time": "8:00 - 8:30"
}, {
  "date": "20. 9. 2020",
  "time": "7:00 - 7:30"
}, {
  "date": "21. 9. 2020",
  "time": "4:00 - 4:30"
}, {
  "date": "22. 9. 2020",
  "time": "10:00 - 10:30"
}, {
  "date": "23. 9. 2020",
  "time": "6:00 - 6:30"
}, {
  "date": "24. 9. 2020",
  "time": "2:00 - 2:30"
}, {
  "date": "25. 9. 2020",
  "time": "4:00 - 4:30"
}];


// Sort row by first date, then time (meeting start time)
console.log(
  '\n\nsmallest First,',
  row.sort((a, b) => datetimeToTS(a.date, a.time) - datetimeToTS(b.date, b.time)),

  '\n\nlargest First,',
  row.sort((a, b) => datetimeToTS(b.date, b.time) - datetimeToTS(a.date, a.time))
)


// this simply parses date & time (meeting start time) and returns a single timeStamp
function datetimeToTS(dateStr, timeStr) {
  const dateMatch = dateStr.match(/(?<dd>\d+).\s*(?<mm>\d+).\s*(?<yy>\d+)/)
  const timeMatch = timeStr.match(/^(?<hh>\d+):(?<mm>\d+)/)
  
  if (dateMatch == null || timeMatch == null)
    throw new Error('Could match date/time format');
  
  const date = new Date(
    dateMatch.groups.yy,
    dateMatch.groups.mm-1,
    dateMatch.groups.dd,
    timeMatch.groups.hh,
    timeMatch.groups.mm
  );
  return date.getTime()
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but my code shows this error => 96:44  error    'datetimeToTS' is not defined         Do you know why is that?

Comment: @DimaMalko u have to add the the `datetimeToTS` function (see the bottom of the interactive example)

Comment: Thank you a lot! This works great, with your explanation i even understand, how it works. You are the best! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```js
rows.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a.time) < Date.parse(b.time) ? -1 : 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the array before you map it:

```
<div>
  {rows && rows.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    }).map(row =>
  <div key={row.id}>
    <div>{row.date}</div>
    <div>{row.time}</div>
    <div>{row.status}</div>
    <br/>
  </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: This one didnt work sadly :( probably because my date is TimeStamp converted into  const myDate = new Date(date.toDate()).toLocaleDateString("cs-CZ"); (this is finall look 22. 9. 2020)